# guice: multiple implementations, different object graphs

Tags: guice, robot-legs-problem

How do you do the following in guice?

There is class `XmlSerializer` that depends on an interface `XmlFormatter`.
There are 2 implementations of `XmlFormatter`: `CompactXmlFormatter` and `PrettyXmlFormatter`.

Another class `MyApplication` depends on 2 instances of `XmlSerializer`. One instance should be configured with a `CompactXmlFormatter` and the other `PrettyXmlFormatter`

```
public class XmlSerializer {
    public XmlSerializer(XmlFormatter formatter) {
       ...
    }
}

public interface XmlFormatter {
    ...
}

public class CompactXmlFormatter implements XmlFormatter {
    ...
}

public class PrettyXmlFormatter implements XmlFormatter {
    ...
}

public class MyApplication {
    public MyApplication(XmlSerializer compactSerializer, XmlSerializer prettySerializer) {
        ...
    }
}
```

How do you construct such a graph?

I know that, once you have the 2 `XmlSerializer` instances, injecting them to `MyApplication` requires annotations in the parameters of the `MyApplication` constructor.

I am more interested in how do you bind `XmlFormatter` to both `CompactXmlFormatter` and `PrettyXmlFormatter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use binding annotations to differentiate each `XmlFormatter`.

In your `Module`:

```
bind(XmlFormatter.class).aannotatedWith(Pretty.class)
    .to(PrettyXmlFormatter.class);
bind(XmlFormatter.class).aannotatedWith(Compact.class)
    .to(CompactXmlFormatter.class);
```

And:

```
@Inject public MyApplication(
    @Compact XmlSerializer compactSerializer, 
    @Pretty XmlSerializer prettySerializer) {
    ...
```

Of course you'll have to define `@Pretty` and `@Compact` annotations:

```
@BindingAnnotation 
@Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD }) 
@Retention(RUNTIME) 
public @interface Pretty {}

@BindingAnnotation 
@Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD }) 
@Retention(RUNTIME) 
public @interface Compact {}
```

Comment: How does that work? because you annotate the `XmlSerializer`, but you bind `XmlFormatter`: `bind(XmlFormatter.class).annotatedWith(Pretty.class)`

Comment: Oops sorry, I misread your question it seems. Then your problem looks like the common "robot leg" problem discussed on Guice WIKI, I think you should take a look at it.

Comment: It looks like the robot legs is what I need, thanks. It look very complicated though compared to Spring...